# how can i pass the info in a text area to a c# method?

Tags: c#, html

have some html like this

```
<form>
user: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
pw  : <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and a c# method to evaluate

```
 string uname = "Bob";
 string pass = "bigballs"; 

 public void Authenticate(string username, string pw)
 {
     if (username == uname && pw == pass)
     {
         /// go to admin area
     }
 }
```

What I want to know is how can this server method access that form data?

Comment: ASP.Net Web forms ? MVC ?

Comment: i dont really want to use any of those, i was wondering if i could just get it

Comment: What do you mean ?? is it a web application ? If so then it must be either ASP.Net web form website or MVC application.

Comment: cant i just use the HttpListener class or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this in asp.net

```
<form>
user: <input type="text" name="firstname" Id= "firstname"><br>
pw  : <input type="text" name="lastname" Id = "lastname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


string strFirstName =  Request.Form["firstname"];
string strLastName =  Request.Form["lastname"];
```